# Calling Python from C++ popen() function

Tags: python, c++, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a small program in C++ that runs a Python script which relies on the popular `requests` Python module. I use C++'s `popen()` function to run a Python script and read the input like so:

```
std::string command = "./fetch.py";
```

and pass it in to `popen()` like so:

```
FILE *in = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
```

I then use `fgets()` in a while loop to get all of the output from the script and store each line in a C++ `std::vector<std::string>`.

The issue lies in running the Python script. I've globally installed the `requests` library (no need for virtual environment since this is the only program my machine will run) and ensured that it can run using the command `sh ./fetch.py` after running `chmod +x ./fetch.py`. However, when ran with `popen()` inside the C++ program, the Python script throws an import error, claiming that the module `requests` is not found. I've double checked Python's `sys.path` to ensure that it includes the path for the `requests` module. I've also tried appending `/bin/bash/ -c` to the command passed into `popen()` in hopes of running the script with bash, and the same thing happened.

I'm running this on a Raspberry Pi with the most recent Raspbian Lite distribution, a Linux derivative, and running the script using Python 3. I installed the `requests` module globally using `pip3`. I am stumped as to why my Python script can find the `requests` module when ran from the command line, but not with `popen()` inside my C++ program, so any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Is there any reason you're not running Boost.Python to embed Python calls in C++? Should be a lot lighter and easier than a separate process.

Comment: can you print the exact error message? does importing "os" work?

Comment: If you can run it with `sh ./fetch.py`, it's not a Python program. What is it exactly?

Comment: `sh ./fetch.py` is not a sensible command to run; just use `./fetch.py` itself.  More to the point: is `PYTHONPATH` the same in the environment of your shell and of your C++ program?

Comment: @alexis I can run it on its own, I put a shebang comment at the top: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: In that case the alternative way to run it must be `python3 ./fetch.py`, *not* with `sh`.